# Correct way of setting a custom FileInfo class to an Iterator

Tags: php, iterator, spl

I am trying to set a custom class to an Iterator through the [`setInfoClass`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/splfileinfo.setinfoclass.php) method:

> Use this method to set a custom class which will be used when getFileInfo and getPathInfo are called. The class name passed to this method must be derived from SplFileInfo.

My class is like this (simplified example):

```
class MyFileInfo extends SplFileInfo
{
    public $props = array(
        'foo' => '1',
        'bar' => '2'
    );
}
```

The iterator code is this:

```
$rit = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
           new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('/some/file/path/'),
           RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
```

Since [`RecursiveDirectoryIterator`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) is by inheritance through [`DirectoryIterator`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) also an [`SplFileInfo`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/class.splfileinfo.php) object, it provides the `setInfoClass` method. It's not listed in the manual, but reflection shows it's there:

```
shell$ php --rc RecursiveDirectoryIterator
// ...
Method [ <internal:SPL, inherits SplFileInfo> public method setInfoClass ] {  
  - Parameters [1] {
    Parameter #0 [ <optional> $class_name ]
  }
}
```

All good up to here, but when iterating over the directory with

```
$rit->getInnerIterator()->setInfoClass('MyFileInfo');
foreach($rit as $file) {
    var_dump( $file );
}
```

I get the following weird result

```
object(MyFileInfo)#4 (3) {
  ["props"]=>UNKNOWN:0
  ["pathName":"SplFileInfo":private]=>string(49) "/some/file/path/someFile.txt"
  ["fileName":"SplFileInfo":private]=>string(25) "someFile.txt"
}
```

So while `MyFileInfo` is picked up, I cannot access it's properties. If I add custom methods, I can invoke them fine, but any properties are UNKNOWN.

If I don't set the info class to the iterator, but to the SplFileInfo object (like shown in the example in the manual), it will give the same UNKNOWN result:

```
foreach($rit as $file) {
    // $file is a SplFileInfo instance
    $file->setInfoClass('MyFileInfo');
    var_dump( $file->getFileInfo() );
}
```

However, it will work when I do

```
foreach($rit as $file) {
    $file = new MyFileInfo($file);
    var_dump( $file );
}
```

Unfortunately, the code I want to use this in is somewhat more complicated and stacks some more iterators. Creating the MyFileInfo class like this is not an option.

So, does anyone know how to get this working or why PHP behaves this weird?

Thanks.

Comment: There is a related bug filed at [#51374](http://bugs.php.net/51374) for SplFileObject but appears to be the same issue.

Comment: @salathe Thanks. Was looking for bugs myself but didn't find this one. That's pretty much the issue I'm facing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't tell you exactly why but it works with

```
class MyFileInfo extends SplFileInfo
{
  public $props;

  public function __construct($filename) {
    $this->props = array(
      'foo' => '1',
      'bar' => '2'
    );

    parent::__construct($filename);
  }
}
```

Comment: This will do. It ain't pretty in the final class and I'm still curious whether this a bug or just something I don't understand, but it will serve my purpose. Thanks!